# Orthogonality of Stirling numbers - simplify a variant thereof

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Stirling numbers satisfy the following **orthogonality condition**. For $k<n$:
$$ \sum_{i=k}^n S(n,i) s(i,k)=0,$$
where $s(i,k)$ and $S(n,i)$ are Stirling numbers of the first and second kind, respectively.

My question: Is there a way to simplify the following
$$ \sum_{i=k}^n \frac{S(n,i) s(i,k)}{2^i}.$$

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that this can be simplified?